# Deleting an entry in SQLite database

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

Iam new to android programming and also to SQLIte.Iam writing the below code from a site.Iam    writing database for contacts.What should I write if I I want to delete some contact with ID as 10?

```
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem in above code ?

Comment: You have to call this function your desired activity at where you want with using "Contact" object.

Comment: no I want to see it deleted in the Logcat

Answer (score 1):

You can check `delete` return to log deleted rows count:

```
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    int n;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    n=db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(contact.getID())});
    db.close();
    Log.v("deleteContact", "Deleted "+String.valueOf(n)+" row(s).");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To match integers, you can't pass string parameter, use following instead:

```
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "=" + contact.getID(), null);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: -1 This adds nothing to OP code!

Comment: write a detailed commentary why -1

Comment: Removed -1 as your answer may address a data type mismatch issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that row is deleted, use this:

```
Cursor cursor = this.dB.query(Table_name,new String[] {"id","column2"}, "id LIKE '" + row_Id + "%'" ,  null , null , null , null );

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
System.out.print("Still Exists");
}
else
{
System.out.print("Deleted");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense... If `delete` fails, exception is thrown.